# How can I add a string to the beginning of each file in a folder in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell

I want to be able to prepend a string to the beginning of each text file in a folder. How can I do this using bash on Linux?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will do that. You could make it more efficient if you are doing the same text to each file...

```
for f in *; do 
  echo "whatever" > tmpfile
  cat $f >> tmpfile
  mv tmpfile $f
done
```

Comment: Both `$f` should be `"$f"`. It would be good to do some error checking too. Also, it changes permissions and ownership of the original file.

Answer (score 26):

You can do it like this without a loop and `cat`

```
sed -i '1i whatever' *
```

if you want to back up your files, use -i.bak

Or using `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==1{$0="whatever\n"$0;}{print $0>FILENAME}' *
```

Comment: your sed comman seems to prepend the string only to the first file

Comment: Why this answer is in the bottom?!

Answer (score 5):

And you can do this using sed in **1 single command** as well

```
for f in *; do
  sed -i.bak '1i\
  foo-bar
  ' ${f}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
FOLDER='path/to/your/folder'
TEXT='Text to prepend'
cd $FOLDER
for i in `ls -1 $FOLDER`; do
     CONTENTS=`cat $i`
     echo $TEXT > $i  # use echo -n if you want the append to be on the same line
     echo $CONTENTS >> $i
done
```

I wouldn't recommending doing this if your files are very big though.

Comment: this is a useless use of `ls` example. Use shell expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this  as well:

```
for f in *; do
  cat <(echo "someline") $f > tempfile
  mv tempfile $f
done
```

It's not much different from the 1st post but does show how to treat the output of the 'echo' statement as a file without having to create a temporay file to store the value.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the ed command to do without temporary files if you like:

```
for file in *; do
  (test ! -f "${file}" || test ! -w "${file}") && continue                # sort out non-files and non-writable files
  if test -s "${file}" && ! grep -Iqs '.*' "${file}"; then continue; fi   # sort out binary files
  printf '\n%s\n\n' "FILE:  ${file}"
  # cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed
  printf '%s\n' H 0a "foobar" . ',p' q | ed -s "${file}"  # dry run (just prints to stdout)
  #printf '%s\n' H 0a "foobar" . wq | ed -s "${file}"     # in-place file edit without any backup
done | less
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest I have worked out.

`sed -i '1s/^/Text` to add then new `file\n/' /file/to/change`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

```
for f in *; 
do
    mv "$f" "whatever_$f"
done
```

Comment: I wanted to format but did not know how to as I'm new here.

Comment: Go start from here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and while you are typing an answer or question see rightbar there is help for formatting

Answer (score -1):

A one-liner: `rename '' string_ *`