# Delete N lines & prepend M lines in each file matching a pattern, recursively

Tags: macos, file, unix, prepend

I'm asking for help with optimizing the following command, but also writing it here for reference if it might help anyone in the future.

I wanted to go through all `.swift` files in the current folder and continue recursively with files in any and all subfolders and then do:

1. Delete the `N` (below 7) first lines in each file
2. **Prepend**, not append, multiple lines, containing characters that otherwise might need escaping (such `//`)

Comment: Since you're answering your own question here (which is fine), you should move the answer part to an actual answer, not make it part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came up with is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5796711/1311272) and has been approved thanks to @EdMorton , but reading the multiline text to prepend from a **file** instead of `echo`ing a string.

**This might only work if you have no space in your paths.**

### Solution

You can copy paste this into the terminal, replace `8`, with how many lines you would like to remove and also replace `~/Desktop/TextToPrepend.txt` with the path to your file with the contents that you would like to prepend.

```sh
find . -name '*.swift' | while IFS= read -r f; do
    cp ~/Desktop/TextToPrepend.txt tmpfile &&
    tail -n +8 "$f" >> tmpfile && 
    mv tmpfile "$f"
done
```

#### Improvements?

It would be even nicer to allow for space n paths and not have to use a file, but rather an in place multiple-line solution, but I ran into issues with a newline and escaping `//`.

### Use case

I just used this to [replace the file header for ALL Swift files in an open source iOS Zilliqa wallet called "Zhip"](https://github.com/OpenZesame/Zhip/commit/c325c7812f1f45d3c40011418caa73287ece4b1b).

The standard for file headers in Xcode is to start each line with a comment `//`.

### Pro-tip

Start your project by add the  file `IDETemplateMacros.plist` as [suggested by this guide](https://medium.com/@silmy/how-to-easily-change-your-file-header-text-in-xcode-347fa77d76f4).

Comment: @EdMorton thx! I updated the solution, did you mean like that? Still using `; do ... done`? I'm a unix commando n00b...

Comment: Would still be interesting with a solution to inline prepend multi line text containing `//` chars :)

Comment: @EdMorton thx a lot, it works beautifully, even more, elegant to use `tail` like that!